# Ruby on Rails template missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to render a templated under

```
public/index.html.erb

  def public_index
    @post = Post.all
    render 'public/index'
  end

Missing template public/index
```

I don't see anything wrong with it. Is public a reserved word or something?

Answer (score 1):

Try using:

```
render :file =>  "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/index.html.erb"
```

Comment: That doesnt work. I used render before and have not had any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
render :template => 'public/index'
```

If this will not help then try following ways

```
render :edit
render action: :edit
render "edit"
render "edit.html.erb"
render action: "edit"
render action: "edit.html.erb"
render "books/edit"
render "books/edit.html.erb"
render template: "books/edit"
render template: "books/edit.html.erb"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit"
render file: "/path/to/rails/app/views/books/edit.html.erb"
```

Check http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

Add this, into your routes.rb file.

```
match '/index', :to => redirect('/index.html')
```

Update

In Rails 4, it should use "get", not "match":

```
get '/index', :to => redirect('/index.html')
```

Comment: if you satisfy with my ans then make it correct and vote up